# How to change number of slides that scrolled in swiper

Tags: slider, swiper.js

I want to change the number of slides from 1 to 3 when I paginate the slider. I mean exactly the property used in slick named slideToScroll.

This is my code:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.product-swiper ', {
  autoplay: {
    delay: 3000,
  },
  slidesPerView: 4,
  spaceBetween: 10,

  pagination: {
    el: '.product-pagination',
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
slidesPerGroup: 3
```

Here is more about it and some useful auto/skip values https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slidesPerGroup